# unable to click on a tab using selenium java for extjs applicaton

Tags: selenium, extjs

I'm trying to select a tab on webpage created using extjs. FirePath is highlighting the tab correctly but click event is not working. Selenium is throwing element not visible error.

```
Exception in thread "main"\org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
      (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) 
    (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 38 milliseconds
```

Here is the HTML code:
I'm trying to select a Tab titled Details with id as tabDetail.

```html
<a class="x-tab x-unselectable x-box-item x-tab-default x-noicon x-tab-noicon x-tab-default-noicon x-top x-tab-top x-tab-default-top x-tab-after-title" role="button" hidefocus="on" unselectable="on" tabindex="0" id="tabDetail" style="right: auto; left: 143px; top: 0px; margin: 0px;">
  <span id="tabDetail-btnWrap" class="x-tab-wrap" unselectable="on">
    <span id="tabDetail-btnEl" class="x-tab-button">
      <span id="tabDetail-btnInnerEl" class="x-tab-inner x-tab-inner-center" unselectable="on"> 
        Detail 
      </span>
      <span role="img" id="tabDetail-btnIconEl" class="x-tab-icon-el  " unselectable="on" style="">
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Please have a look at the [ask] section and provide a [mcve]. This will allow those that can help to actually help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until element is visible. Use explicit wait -

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);   
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[2]")));
// Now click on element
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]")).click();
```